# Error when opening successfully deployed app on Heroku

Tags: asp.net, angular, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku from github. The build is successful and the deploy is made but I am getting this:
`Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details`
I've tried everything I found online but nothing seems to be working. What could be wrong? My app is ASP NET Core-Angular-Postgre and I am using the packages: heroku/nodejs and https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack. This is the error log:

```
2021-06-08T10:26:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded    
  
2021-06-08T10:38:09.898983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bucuriesicredinta.herokuapp.com request_id=bcb5093b-6b3c-4713-bf35-11d2c087b574 fwd="109.103.246.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https  
   
2021-06-08T10:38:10.307972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bucuriesicredinta.herokuapp.com request_id=c9df055e-341c-4676-962b-6fb4c9e90c5d fwd="109.103.246.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https                                                                               2021-06-08T10:38:10.740207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bucuriesicredinta.herokuapp.com request_id=4c639bfb-304c-4f60-a814-26b973afd0eb fwd="109.103.246.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've read that errors starting with H are caused by the Procfile, but I can't seem to find that. Should it be in my root folder? And what should it contain?
Also, this is my package.json and I don't know if I should write something inside of "scripts", it was automatically made like this:

```
{
  "name": "joyandfaith",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/[my_username]"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/[my_username]"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/[my_username]"
}
```

I am running out of ideas. Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: I have a manually made Procfile in the root folder of my project containing this: `web:node src/server.js` but I don't think it should be like this.

Comment: what is `base href` in index.html pointing to ?

Comment: It’s `<base href=“/”>`

Comment: After adding the Procfile I am getting error H10 with `Starting process with command node src/server.js. Cannot find module /app/src/server.js` So I guess it’s not the right content in the Procfile.